# How to scroll using coordinates with appium

Tags: java, android, selenium, automation, appium

im trying to scroll in a native android app by using the method below

```
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80);
int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
int startx = size.width / 2;

driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 3000);
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

but at `driver.swipe` it gives me an error that says

> The method swipe(int, int, int, int, int) is undefined for the type AndroidDriver

can anyone help me fix this? i have been searching forever trying to find a solution but i have had no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TouchAction` instead `.swipe`:

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
action.press(x, y).moveTo(x, y).release().perform();
```

You can also implement `x y` with `PointOption`, like this:

1. `.press(new PointOption().withCoordinates(x, y))`

   Or
2. `.press(PointOption.point(x, y))`

Following import:

```
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
```

[TouchAction](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/#scrolling)

[PointOption](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/touch/offset/PointOption.html)

Comment: hey bro it says that The method press(PointOption) in the type TouchAction is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)

Comment: `press(PointOption) ` try insert with this value: `press(new PointOption().withCoordinates(value, value))`.

Comment: thanks bro thats working but do you know if theres a way to make it scroll more slowly? it scrolls extremely fast

Comment: Like this: `.press(...).waitAction(Duration.ofSeconds(2)).moveTo(...)`. You need import: `import java.time.Duration;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this technique instead of appium methods.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<>();
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", scrollObject);
```