# How to scroll to the element with resourceId or id if you don't have the text or content-desc as attributes of that element in Appium

Tags: java, appium, ui-automation, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to execute this script but the scroll function is not working, I have rechecked the resourceId, it is correct and this method works when used with text("<desired_text>") or description(<desired_text>) in place of resourceId("</element_id>"). But I don't have those attribute values in the app.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().resourceId(\""+resourceId+"\"));"));
element.click();
```

The output is showing NoSuchElementException but scroll function is not working then it is obvious that NoSuchElementException will be thrown because desired element is not in current focus of the device's screen, it can't be located.

output:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '13.4', java.version: '11.0.19'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [32fc3d21-6a7f-46eb-b8a2-99f18bdd920a, findElement {using=-android uiautomator, value=new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().resourceId("<masking_the_id>"));}]
Capabilities {appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:databaseEnabled: false, appium:desired: {automationName: UIAutomator2, platformName: ANDROID}, appium:deviceApiLevel: 33, appium:deviceManufacturer: XXXXX, appium:deviceModel: XXXXXXX, appium:deviceName: XXXXXX, appium:deviceScreenDensity: 450, appium:deviceScreenSize: 1080x2408, appium:deviceUDID: XXXXX, appium:javascriptEnabled: true, appium:locationContextEnabled: false, appium:networkConnectionEnabled: true, appium:pixelRatio: 2.8125, appium:platformVersion: 13, appium:statBarHeight: 70, appium:takesScreenshot: true, appium:viewportRect: {height: 2133, left: 0, top: 70, width: 1080}, appium:warnings: {}, appium:webStorageEnabled: false, platformName: ANDROID}
Session ID: 32fc3d21-6a7f-46eb-b8a2-99f18bdd920a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try inspecting element using [appium inspector](https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector/releases) and check whether it is able to identify object by locator id. Make sure to specify the entire package name with the resource id `com.org.android:id/submitBtn`

Comment: I did pass the whole resourceId with package name but it was not working. I have modified this scroll method with new logic.

Comment: we have to monitor execution. Object might not be in view port of the application. You can get co-ordinates of the object using Appium and try out scroll with it. Once you reach to point where Object is in view port you will be able to access it. 
You can try first answer given to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58090767/how-to-scroll-using-coordinates-with-appium. Make sure to check comments as well

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted to implement new logic for this

```
public boolean scrollDownGestureForUnknownElementAction(String element_path){
boolean canScrollMore;
do{
   canScrollMore = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript
                    ("mobile: scrollGesture", ImmutableMap.of("direction", "down", "percent", 50.0, "left", 100, "top", 100, "width", 200, "height", 800, "speed", 1500));
      try {
         if (driver.findElement(By.id(element_path)).isDisplayed());
                break;
          }
          catch (NoSuchElementException exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
                return false;
          }
}while (canScrollMore);
        return canScrollMore;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code,

```
HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("strategy", "-android uiautomator");
map1.put("selector", "UiSelector().resourceId(\"test123\")");

driver.executeScript("mobile: scroll", map1);

driver.findElement(AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator("UiSelector().resourceId(\"test123\")")).click();
```